# can't install eclipse plugin "m2e connector for build-helper-maven-plugin 0.15.0.201109290002"

Tags: eclipse, gwt, maven, eclipse-indigo, m2e

i just tried to move from helios to maven with my gwt 2.4 application. so i began to follow the steps here:
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WorkingWithMaven

but on step 3 - installing the feature "m2e connector for build-helper-maven-plugin" i get an error from Eclipse:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: m2e connector for build-helper-maven-plugin     0.15.0.201109290002 (org.sonatype.m2e.buildhelper.feature.feature.group 0.15.0.201109290002)
  Missing requirement: m2e connector for build-helper-maven-plugin 0.15.0.201109290002 (org.sonatype.m2e.buildhelper 0.15.0.201109290002) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.m2e.jdt [1.1.0,1.2.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e connector for build-helper-maven-plugin 0.15.0.201109290002 (org.sonatype.m2e.buildhelper.feature.feature.group 0.15.0.201109290002)
    To: org.sonatype.m2e.buildhelper [0.15.0.201109290002]
```

Is there a workaround for that or did I do something wrong?

Comment: I get exactly the same message on Gentoo Linux

Comment: i dug around a bit:
it seems that the jboss repository is wrong. so i tried to find another repo with "m2e connector for build-helper-maven-plugin" but had no luck so far.

Comment: FWIW - Since m2e has moved to the Eclipse foundation in the Indigo I have seen several problems. I had to open a bug ticket to get Sonatype to finally give up an update site url for the SVN-M2E connector! Good luck!

Comment: Still getting this mysterious error in 2015, apatrelli's answer did work though: https://repository.sonatype.org/content/repositories/forge-sites/m2e-extras/0.14.0/N/0.14.0.201109282148/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is not the GWT Eclipse plugin but m2e, that currently is at 1.0.x version, and not 1.1.0 or higher as requested by the build-helper connector version 0.15.
I suggest to install the build-helper connector later, and try to install the 0.14 version (that works on my machine).
Use this repository: https://repository.sonatype.org/content/repositories/forge-sites/m2e-extras/0.14.0/N/0.14.0.201109282148/

If you need an update site (e.g. because you are working with RAD and can only use an update site) there is a modified 0.15.0 update site definition: [m2eclipse with 0.14.0 connector](http://www.martinsland.de/img/m2e0.14.0.zip)

To get it working do this:

- Go to Help\Install new software\
- Click on Add
- Click on Local
- Add the unzipped folder as location

In the selection choose the m2e connector for build-helper-maven-plugin in version 0.14.0.

Comment: thx but how to install older versions? - i never needed this? besides on adding "http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/" to update sites i stumbled across this bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=338495
and i am very unsure if this plugin will help with an very nasty compilation error i get only in indigo with my gwt/maven app - but let's see

Comment: Sorry for the late response, Stackoverflow did not notify me. See the updated answer, I've added the repository to use.

Comment: Thanks for the 0.14.0. With that help I got it working on my machine. I edited your answer with a link to my modified update zip.

Comment: updated repository for eclipse 2019-12: https://repository.sonatype.org/content/repositories/forge-sites/m2e-extras/0.15.0/N/0.15.0.201206251206/

Answer (score 12):

Found a solution. You can install the correct version with no dependency failure via your eclipse console.

1. Open the relevant pom.xml, via the overview view, you should see the error message in red at the top saying "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:buid..(Click fro details)
2. Right click and select discover m2e connector
3. Eclipse marketplace will be displayed, with thecorrect and required m2e connector.
4. select the buildhelper and click finish.
5. Follow instructions and install, restart eclipse
6. Voila, following next build, these maven errors should not occur anymore.

Comment: I love this generic solution which is still working today.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue where STS (3.9.1.Release) was saying I had an update for:
"m2e connector for build-helper-maven-plugin" but then it would never complete and kept bugging me about it.

I added the following SonaType repository:
https://repository.sonatype.org/content/repositories/forge-sites/m2e-marketplace-p2-repo/

Then STS was able to do the update it wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

To install required version of m2e you could use following repository [m2e 1.1 milestone](http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/milestones/1.1).
It's not well tested yet but I did not notice any error.

Answer (score 1):

In case if you are still looking for “m2e connector for build-helper-maven-plugin 0.15.0." releases

https://repository.sonatype.org/content/repositories/forge-sites/m2e-extras/0.15.0/N/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the last message in the [thread you asked at m2e-users at eclipse.org](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/m2e-users/msg01880.html). I have not tried it, so.

Comment: yes i just read it. the problem is without the jboss site i can't find the build helper plugin (can't add http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.0 as update site because of: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=338495)

Answer (score 0):

Installing m2e >1 from http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/ solved the problem for me .